# for multiple columns based on a condition given about target column ,summing up the number of matches given for each individual columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and filtering there based on an condition on target column `(data['Retention Flag']=='Retained')` , again applying one more condition like summing up the number of value which equals to any integer ( here it is 84 ) for each column.

I am having the `non_cat_column=['CONTRACT TERM', 'FINANCED AMOUNT',  'INTEREST RATE', 'EMI',.....etc]`

I wrote a code which is working fine, by filtering the target column by a condition ,converting the columns to dict, identify their values and also the loop for summing up the matches. Is there any other better method or easily available/syntax for the same.

```
non_cat_column=['CONTRACT TERM', 'FINANCED AMOUNT', 'ACTIVATION DATE', 'CONTRACT END DATE', 'CONTRACT MATURITY DATE', 'INTEREST RATE', 'Ex Showroom', 'EMI']


for feature in non_cat_column:
    print(feature)
    print(data[feature][data['Retention Flag']=='Retained'].tail())
    print('Values of each columns which have the Retention Flag as "Retained" in dictionary format')
    print(data[feature][data['Retention Flag']=='Retained'].to_dict().values())
    print('....the total number of 84 values in the feature column where Retention Flag=Retained.....')
    print(sum(1 for value in (data[feature][data['Retention Flag']=='Retained'].to_dict().values()) if value==84))
```

output:

```
CONTRACT TERM
13956    84
13957    60
13958    60
13959    24
13960    36
Name: CONTRACT TERM, dtype: int64
Values of each columns which have the Retention Flag as "Retained" in 
dictionary format
dict_values([84, 60, 84, 84, 60, 84, 60, 48, 60, 84, 60, 84, 60. .... etc 
])
.....the total number of 84 values in the feature column where Retention 
Flag=Retained.....  172
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Okay @desertnaut